# What kind of armor do men of the Night's Watch wear?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, armor

I have been watching Game of Thrones and was wondering what type of armor do the brothers of the Night's Watch wear?

Comment: Are you just looking for the name of the type of armour that they wear?

Comment: http://cdn-media.hollywood.com/images/l/Sam.jpg - Leather, with matching leather.

Comment: But sam was wearing different kind during sword practice. I thought it was brigandine

Comment: There is no mention in the books that the Night's Watch wore other types of armour than warriors elsewhere in Westeros. Though I do not recall anyone ever wearing heavy plate armour, such as the Mountain, Victarion Greyjoy, etc have been mentioned as wearing. It has been mentioned that they wear black chain mail, and I assume leather as well.

Comment: Definitely the lighter types - leather, chainmail, maybe a really light scale.

Comment: Most descriptions from the first book state "boiled leather" and indicate mail at times. Different people wear different armor, seems to be a whatever-they-can-get scenario.

Comment: It's also far too cold to wear steel armor all the time. Definitely a bad idea to be wearing something like plate mail. I remember that when they designed the armor for the NW in the show, they stuck to mostly leather and fur because of their practicality in the cold.

Comment: I think the answer is "black".

Comment: From what is seen on screen, they wear thick leather armor as mail or plate would become too cold and become damaged and rusty in the north.  The leather would help keep them warm and allow for lighter movement and stealth while on rangings.  Whereas mail or plate would be too heavy, shiny, and clunky.

Answer (score 12):

Other answers are either lacking in good material or contain wrong assumptions therefore I feel obliged to add an answer.

There are two types of Armaments for Members of Night's Watch.

1. Personal equipment
2. Night's Watch's standard issue

---

### Personal Equipment

Highborn members of the Night's Watch often bring their own armor with them and it is allowed to use as long as it is black.

Chief examples would be the two members that we know from books i.e. Samwell Tarly and Ser Waymar Royce.

From AGOT Prologue:

> He [Ser Waymar Royce] wore black leather boots, black woolen pants,
>   black moleskin gloves, and **a fine supple coat of gleaming black
>   ringmail over layers of black wool and boiled leather**. Ser Waymar
>   had been a Sworn Brother of the Night’s Watch for less than half a
>   year, but **no one could say he had not prepared for his vocation**.
>   At least insofar as his wardrobe was concerned.

So it is evident from this passage that Ser Waymar had brought his own equipment with him because it is explicitly said that he had prepared for his work himself when he came to join the NW.

From AGOT:

> It was soon revealed that the new recruit [Samwell Tarly] had brought
>   his own armor with him; **padded doublet, boiled leather, mail and
>   plate and helm, even a great wood-and-leather shield blazoned with the
>   same striding huntsman he wore on his surcoat**. As none of it was
>   black, however, Ser Alliser insisted that he reequip himself from the
>   armory.

So here you can see Sam also brought complete armor with him when he came to the Wall but unlike Ser Waymar, his equipment was not black therefore he had to reequip from the armory.

So we can see, Highborns who bring their own armor bring the whole deal with them. The equipment listed here is:

1. Chain mail
2. Helmets
3. Shields
4. Plate Armor
5. Padded doublets
6. Boiled leather

Chainmail offers protection against vertical strikes from swords, pivoting thrusts of low intensity given by swords or spears and arrows depending on distance. Helmets protect one's head. Shields are used to block blows. Plate Armor does everything a Chainmail does but it is also efficient against high intensity pivoting thrusts. On downside, Plate Armor is heavy and affects mobility therefore is unsuitable for ranging or manning the wall. Padded doublets provide some safety from jolting impacts of blows. Boiled leather is very hard leather which can be used to protect one from blows.

---

### Night's Watch standard issue

Night's Watch has its own armory and armor. They forge their own weapons with the steel they get as a gift from Lords or the steel they purchase. Night's Watch provides the following to its members and recruits:

1. Chain mails
2. Helmets
3. Boiled leather
4. Shields
5. Padding made of wool
6. Hauberk
7. Coif

In AGOT, we see Jon fighting with this equipment:

> Under **black wool, boiled leather, and mail**, sweat trickled icily
>   down Jon’s chest as he pressed the attack.

We know it's not his own equipment because after that he went to the Armory and put it all back there.

Also, When Jon tries to go back to Winterfell in AGOT:

> He would need to find new clothes soon; most like, he’d need to steal
>   them. He was clad in black from head to heel; high leather riding
>   boots, roughspun breeches and tunic, sleeveless leather jerkin, and
>   heavy wool cloak. His longsword and dagger were sheathed in black
>   moleskin, and **the hauberk and coif in his saddlebag were black
>   ringmail**.

Regarding the Helmets we see:

> His [Samwell Tarly's] girth required Donal Noye to take apart a mail hauberk and refit
>   it with leather panels at the sides. To **get a helm over his head the
>   armorer had to detach the visor**.

Some members wear plate armor as well although it is unclear whether it is their personal (As they are highborn) or issued from the Watch's armory:

> Thoren Smallwood dismounted beside the trunk, **dark in his plate and
>   mail**. “Look at that face. Small wonder men feared them, when they
>   first came to Westeros. I’d like to take an axe to the bloody thing
>   myself.”

Also when Jon was climbing a mountain during ranging on Skirling pass in ACOK:

> They each took a long coil of rope. Stonesnake carried a bag of iron
>   spikes as well, and a small hammer with its head wrapped in thick
>   felt. **Their garrons they left behind, along with their helms, mail,
>   and Ghost**.

Jon was also seen once wearing a plate when Stannis asked to see him in ASOS:

> He hung **his mail and plate** inside the armory, returned to his own
>   cell, discarded his sweat- stained clothes, and donned a fresh set of
>   blacks.

---

Now you may be wondering why do Men of the Night's Watch seem to prefer chain mail instead of a full plate armor. The reason is already mentioned above. Plate is heavy and hampers mobility which is crucial for a ranger out there in the wild or for a guard standing atop the wall.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Sam makes several mentions of wearing chain mail while ranging beyond the wall.

But I would need to take some time and look it up.

I've always wondered if Jon brought black gear with him or dyed his gear when he got there.

Comment: Could you look it up, and add references?

Comment: You are correct Sam did wear armor  (Chain mail) beyond the wall. While it is unclear if Jon brought his own armor or not (Other highborns did), he is also seen wearing armor many times

Answer (score -1):

Your question is quite unclear. On the wall, there are multiple classes of brothers:

1-Kind of civilians: Builders, cooks, maesters and assistants. This kind of brothers is not deemed fit to train for arms, and most of the cases, the masters in arms
2-Soldiers : This is the most common type of brothers on the wall, they are trained to wield a sword and perhaps use a bow and arrow. Their day to day tasks are to mount gards on the wall and engage enemy in defense of the wall.
NB: the first and second category are very close, and their tasks may be confused, and some sources mention that :

> Every man in the Watch walks the wall, and all are expected to bare steel in its defense, but the rangers are the true fighting men of the Watch (I: 372)

However we never heard of Sam Tarly walking the wall. So...

3-Rangers: These are the gifted unfortunate, that have joined the wall for one reason or another. They're hence given the toughest quests. Rangers often dwell behind the wall, and seldom on it. They are generally good trackers and stealth masters. They know very well their way in the land of the far north. Qhorin Halfhand and Benjen Stark are very known rangers.

Regarding the armour now that is the core of your question. The first category doesn't require one, so what they wear around is what keeps them warmest, so any kind of animal fur or skin or leather would do.(I am not taking into consideration the latest events on the wall were resources were scarce and everybody engaged in battle).
Recruits of the Watch wear often

> roughspun black (I: 149)

because such described wear is hard to get by and

> On the Wall, a man gets only what he earns (I: 150)

The second category, is the one destined more for battle. However, they prefer boiled leather to any other protection. The main reason behind that is that steel is cold, and gets colder with the cold of the north, can even cause problems during long watches. 
The third category, is the rangers'. Well this category even though it seems to be the most danger exposed one, is the least worried about protection, for several reasons. If they go detected on their reckon missions, no kind of armour would save them. If they stay exposed in the cold with heavy armour, they'd die of cold. So they prefer skin.

> Rangers often share skins for warmth (III: 169)

This is an illustration of Qhorin Halfhand, and you clearly see the wolfskin around his neck:

[image: Qhorin Halfhand by Matt Olson]

Oh, and of course, all these categories have cloaks of course, black washed out cloaks. 
And before I end my answer (which cannot really be considered as answer for lack of details about the question) I have to add that in order to answer this question properly, we need to study the armour of the free folks. They're more exposed to war than the black watch, and they're accustomed to war in cold. Some have bones for armour, some boiled leather, and whatever armour the brothers of the watch use, is either stolen from free folks (it goes the other way around also) either inspired by them. After all, a seasoned brother of the night watch, is very similar to any one of the free folk, I guess the circumstances change a person.

PS: I heavily relied in this answer on this excellent [website](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/Concordance/Section/3.3./).

Comment: Where did you find the definition of "soldiers" as something different than rangers? IIRC both in the books and tv series there is no such distinction

Comment: @Ciacciu I'll have to admit much of the distinction is a personal effort. In fact the confusion isn't between rangers and soldiers, but between the, lets call them, civilians on the wall and the soldiers. There are two different types of people in the wall, Rangers and the rest. And the rest may be cooks, stewards, builders or what I called soldiers. But we find through the book that the builders are often used in battles, also cooks, and in a much lesser rate the stewards that are usually Sam Tarly like.

Comment: Are builders really "often used in battles"? IMO it's just the sheer necessity that makes them fight, the same necessity that, in the books, makes it a good idea to give crossbows to Mole Town's whores.
I don't want to sound mean, but I think your answer relies too much on personal interpretation.
Also Jon Snow is a steward, although definitely a peculiar one :)

Comment: I believe so yeah, builders are physically able so yeah. My answer is not personal opinion, I just relied on a division that exists (no doubt over that) in order to answer more clearly the question, rather that than say "well they use boiled leather" that would be more generic and inaccurate.

Comment: All NW members train for fighting before being assigned to different orders. Rangers have their focus on fighting but that does not mean that Stewards and Builders are not fighters. **They do train for fighting as Sam and Jon did despite being part of Order of Stewards**

Comment: Also, since when do "Roughspun black" and "Skins" count as armament? And Ranger don't stay behind the wall, they go beyond it. I did not gave you a DV when I last skimmed this answer an hour ago, but sorry, you deserve it.

Comment: Everything in your answer is based on assumptions and none of it is based in facts provided by show or books.

Comment: @Aegon, fair enough. When I said behind the wall, i meant beyond it. Doesn't really make sense for a ranger to remain on the safe side of the wall does it? Still, bad wording from my part. 
And yes, NW men are all trained for fighting, and are later filtered and assigned their respective roles based on their skills. What they wear during their everyday life depends on that assignment and not on the fact that they once trained for fighting. I find it really hard to see a cook wearing a ringmail. Roughspun and skin aren't knight armament but are footsoldier's. [continued]

Comment: Yes, my answer is really vastly based on speculation, I have however provided the seldom book passages i found from the book at the time of writing this answer.