# Why would the White Walkers have a large iron chain in episode 6 “Beyond the Wall”?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I can consider that the rescue could happen as shown, but why would the White Walkers have a large iron chain for a possible

> dragon rescue

in episode 6 “Beyond the Wall”?

Comment: Please split this into two questions as you have two questions. The first question has been asked a few times at MTVSE and I think here too. The second question will be answered with we don't know.

Comment: Please do not put spoilers in titles, and use spoiler markup. Regarding your question about white walker giants - they were shown in one of the previous episodes, though if you're willing to ask about them please do so in a separate question. For your first question, see [How did the Wights get the chain for doing this?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/79148/44222)

Comment: Shouldn't the dupe go the other way? Or possible just merge them?

Comment: @Skooba 'Tis done. IonHawk, the answer to your question about chains is now [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/167760/31394); if you still want to know about the White Walkers' giants, please post that as a [new question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).